# Configuring SSL in Spring vs NGINX

Tags: java, spring, nginx, ssl

Say I were to develop a backend for a mobile app using Spring Boot & wished to add SSL via a Letsencrypt (or a similar provider) certificate. The backend will be accessible only via NGINX.

If I understand it correctly, I could configure SSL in either Spring or NGINX. What would be the best practice? Is there any downside if I were to configure SSL in NGINX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx seems to be simpler to configure TLS/SSL with plain certificate and key files, but with Spring and Java you have a bit more security using keystores to store the server certificate + private key, and also you exclude a possiblity of a man-on-the middle between Nginx and the Spring backend. There is a little bit more complexity and learning curve with the last approach, but **spring-boot** helps a lot with it.

Besides TLS/SSL Ngix has also [other features](https://nginx.org/en/) like load balancing and caching that may be interessting for your use case.